# What is the meaning of a discriminant graphically?

Tags: quadratics

I know that if $b^2-4ac>0$, then there are real solutions and so on. 
But for any quadratic function, where is the discriminant present in the plot? 
For example, $x^2-8x+7=f(x)$. 
[image]

Now how is $\Delta=36$ associated with the graph?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function#Vertex

Comment: $\Delta = 36 = (7-1)^2$. For monic polynomial, the discriminant is the product of  squares of distances among the roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square root of the discriminant is the distance between the zeros in case we have $a=1$. In your plot we have
$$7-1 = 6=\sqrt{36}=\sqrt{\Delta}.$$

**Proof:**

We have
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a},$$
so
$$x_1-x_2= \frac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a} - \frac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a} = \frac{2\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}= \frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{a}=\sqrt{\Delta}.$$

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Yes, but the author is asking about the meaning in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about the quadratic formula:

$$ x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

then the difference between the roots is:

$$\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{a} $$

i.e. $\sqrt{\Delta}/a$.